# Writing Custom MPEG4 Tags (stik, TVSeasonNum, etc.)

Tags: taglib-sharp

I'd like to us [Taglib-Sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp) to a small media organizer program I am working on. I want to write metadata to a MPEG4 file things like artwork and what not I have figured out. However Apple uses some custom tags for classificing something as "HD" or a "TV Show" tags like the `stik` tag need to be set to `TV Show`. I'm having a hard time understanding how I can write these "custom" tags? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag customTag = (TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag)file.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Apple, true);
var vector = new TagLib.ByteVector();
vector.Add((byte)10);
customTag.SetData("stik", vector, (int)TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleDataBox.FlagType.ContainsData);
```

Comment: "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')" System.ArgumentNullException